# ImageViews created programmatically error of "unresolved identifier"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

I have 8 ImageViews that i called Left1, Left2, Left3, Left4 and the same with "Right". I created them programmatically in tht view did load like that:

-**View Did Load**

```
var Left1 : UIImageView
Left1 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(20, 92, 116, 62));
Left1.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view.addSubview(Left1)
```

And there's a button, where i use this ImageViews:

**-Button Function**

```
Right1.center.y = 0 - 31
Left1.center.y = 0 - 31
Right1.hidden = false
Left1.hidden = false
```

But Xcode gives me the error: *Use of unresolved identifier 'Right1'* and *Use of unresolved identifier 'Left1'*.

And this for every single ImageViews

Can you help me?

Comment: can you show more code.

Comment: Well actually that's all the code I have, but repeated for every ImageViews. I 've just added in the edit that i did the declaration in the view did load, if it can help, but yes, that's all. Just a button and some imageviews

Comment: Add the view did load method and class implementation to see which is your code structure

Comment: Just a small tip, you should not uppercase your first character in your variable name,  you can have a look there [here](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#language) if you want more details.

Comment: Where are you setting up these image views? Where is your second piece of code executed. It looks like your first code is within a function, and because they are being created in there they will be local to that function

Comment: I edited, let's see if now you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sam pointed, you should declare your views as properties of your class, not as local variables:

```
var Left1: UIImageView!
var Right1: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Left1 = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(20, 92, 116, 62));
    Left1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(Left1)

    //same for Right1
}
```

Comment: Ok now it doesn't give me any error, but when i debug the imageviews don't appear..

Comment: @A.J. add `Left1.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()` in `viewDidLoad` if you wish to locate your view visually

Comment: You are right, I thought that "tintColor" was background color. Anyway, now it works, thanks!